# To solve this problem just follow this rule or is there another possibility?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

To solve this problem just follow this rule or is there another possibility?

[image]

```
Solve[(3 Sqrt[2])/Sin[60 Degree] == x/Sin[45 Degree], {x}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
{{Ax, Ay}, {Bx, By}, {Cx, Cy}} = 
      First @ AASTriangle[60 Degree, 45 Degree, 3 Sqrt[2]];

b = Sqrt[Cx^2 + Cy^2] // Simplify
2 Sqrt[3]

c = Bx // Simplify
3 + Sqrt[3]
```

Comment: I did not know this function

Answer (score 5):

```
triangle = AASTriangle[60 Degree, 45 Degree, 3 Sqrt[2]];

unknownsides = Line /@ Partition[RotateRight@triangle[[1]], 2, 1];
ArcLength /@ unknownsides
```

> {2 Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3] (1 + Sqrt[3])}

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can describe the triangle using vectors(g is the horizontal side) :

```
 Solve[ x {Cos[60 °], Sin[60 °]} == {g, 0} +3 Sqrt[2] {-Cos[45 °], Sin[45 °]}, {x, g}]
 (*{{x -> 2 Sqrt[3], g -> 3 + Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve for both unknown sides

```
Solve[{c^2 == a^2 + b^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[theta] /. {
     {c -> x, a -> 3 Sqrt[2], theta -> 45 Degree},
     {c -> 3 Sqrt[2], a -> x, theta -> 60 Degree}}, x > 0, b > 0} // 
  Flatten, {x, b}]

(* {{x -> 2 Sqrt[3], b -> 3 + Sqrt[3]}} *)
```